# Not applying custom directive format in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, directive

I have written the custom directive to format the number (Ex: BE06377004247122
 to BE06 3770 0424 7122). I don't want to change the model value. so I am assigned the formatted value to the element. Value formatted after any interaction with that control. but initially, it's not changing. Value is formatted in afterviewinit but it not reflected in control.
[image]

```
@Directive({ selector: "[ibanFormatter]" })
export class IBANFormatterDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    private el: HTMLInputElement;
    private ibanPipe: FormatIBANAccountNumberPipe
    constructor(
        public model: NgModel,
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
    )
    {
        this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.ibanPipe = new FormatIBANAccountNumberPipe();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.el.value = this.ibanPipe.transform(this.model.model);
    }
@HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
    onFocus(value) {
        this.el.value = this.ibanPipe.parse(value); // opossite of transform
    }
```

Comment: If you want to format a string only to display it, and not change its value, consider using a pipe instead of a directive.

Comment: No, it's editable

Comment: `I don't want to change the model value`. Make up your mind ...

Comment: No, what I am saying,  it should not change the model value.that's why I assigned formatted value to  ElementRef.nativeElement.value. the value should  be stored DB like BE06 3770 0424 7122 not BE06377004247122

Comment: Sry for misscomunication

Comment: Okay, so when the user inputs the IBAN, it needs to be formatted, then saved  ?

Comment: by initially it should be shown as BE06 3770 0424 7122. if user focus to that control then it should be BE06377004247122.

Comment: Okay, something [**like this**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzg1hh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fspace-remover.directive.ts) ?